# Hp printer wont print because ink empty

Tags: hp

My windows XP computer has no problem printing to an HP printer that thinks it has no black ink.  However the XUBUNTU driver does not want to go any further.  How can you tell it to go ahead anyway cause there is ink in this refilled cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11526603&postcount=13

1. delete printer from computer via settings menu
2. re-add printer by opening terminal and typing hp-setup

Apparently, this forces the computer to ignore the low-ink message.

Answer (score 0):

I just went thru this on Ubuntu Mate with a MX850 I've had for years.  I saw it stated Cyan was empty.   What does Cyan have to do with anything.  Not a mission critical color.

I thankfully find a bag that has some ink cartridges and I had Cyan.  Pop it in, and it lights up red.  None of the other colors (yellow, magenta, black small and big) all not lit up.

I reboot the printer.

I check linux and now I see Cyan full, all the errors go away.

So that solved my issue, but this feels more like a arbitrary block to getting things done.  Not sure of a software workaround to this.